# How can I stop on a new line when using read_to_string?

Tags: sockets, tcp, rust

I am writing a socket server in Rust, and have implemented response/send code. The main problem is that the method `read_to_string` works until the connection is closed, not until a newline is presented.

For example, in this code,

```
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::Write;
use std::io::Read;

fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) {
    let conn = stream;
    let conn = send(conn, "Hello!");
    let mut conn = send(conn, "Bye!");
    fn send(mut stream: TcpStream, s: &str) -> TcpStream {
        let giver = format!("{}\n", s);
        let _ = stream.write(giver.into_bytes().as_slice());
        return stream;
    }
    let mut response: String = "".to_string();
    let length = conn.read_to_string(&mut response); // ignore here too
    println!("Message:\n{}\n\nLength: {}", response, length.unwrap());
}
```

The server will wait for a disconnect before presenting any data.

How can I make it so that the response will parse on newline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to read a single line, the method for which is called [`BufRead::read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line). You can wrap something implementing `Read` in a [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufReader.html):

```
use std::io::{Write, BufRead, BufReader};
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn handle_client(mut conn: TcpStream) {
    writeln!(&mut conn, "Hello!").expect("Unable to write");
    writeln!(&mut conn, "Bye!").expect("Unable to write");

    let mut response = String::new();
    let mut conn = BufReader::new(conn);
    let length = conn.read_line(&mut response).expect("unable to read");
    println!("Message:\n{}\n\nLength: {}", response, length);
}

fn main() {}
```

---

Additional notes on the original code:

1. **Don't ignore errors**. If you want to ignore errors, then Rust may not be a language you enjoy using. Errors are designed to be hard to ignore.
2. There's no reason to re-bind `stream` to `conn`, just make it mutable.
3. Use the `write!` and `writeln!` macros to simplify formatting to something that implements `Read`.
4. Don't use `"".to_string`, just use `String::new`.
5. There's no reason to list the type for `response` twice (`: String`, `= String::new()`), just let type inference handle it.
6. Explicit `return` statements are not idiomatic Rust.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just started out with Rust recently and are still getting used to the general syntax/ methodology. This really helps.